# how to access @Html.RadioButtonFor in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a coded a radio button in MVC razor.below is the code for it.

```
 @{
           var LinkRadioName = "_Link";
            var ContentRadioName ="_Content";
            var TextRadioName = "_Text";
            var ExternalLinkRadioName ="_ExternalLink";
            var FilelistRadioName ="_Filelist";


            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MenuType, true, new { @id = LinkRadioName })
            @Html.Label("Link")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MenuType, false, new { @id = ContentRadioName })
            @Html.Label("Content")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MenuType, true, new { @id = TextRadioName })
            @Html.Label("Text")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MenuType, false, new { @id = ExternalLinkRadioName })
            @Html.Label("External Link")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MenuType, true, new { @id = FilelistRadioName })
            @Html.Label("File List")

        }
```

can any one help me ,as to how can i access this radiobutton set in jquery:

i have a code like this

```
@Html.RadioButton("TypeOfmenu", 1)Link
@Html.RadioButton("TypeOfmenu", 2)Content
@Html.RadioButton("TypeOfmenu", 3)Text
@Html.RadioButton("TypeOfmenu", 4)ExternalLink
@Html.RadioButton("TypeOfmenu", 5)Filelist
```

and i access it very easily in jquery like

```
 $("input[name$='TypeOfmenu']").click(function () {

        var Selectedvalue = $(this).val();
});
```

is there any way to access the  @Html.RadioButtonFor control in d same way like

```
 $("input[name$='MenuType']").click(function () {

        var Selectedvalue = $(this).val();
});
```

??????

please help me as i m very new in MVC as well as jquery.

Comment: its better that you change the click handler to `change`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are accessing the values in your function with `this.val()`, you can just bind your event to all radio buttons

```
$(":radio").click(function () {

        var Selectedvalue = $(this).val();
        //OR
        //var Selectedvalue = this.value;
});
```